# Using a loop in bicep gives casting error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I've read about for [loops in bicep files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#array-elements) and finally comes to this code. It has 2 arrays for users and app _(both needs different permissions). For access policies I loop over each item.

```
param keyVault_name string
param webapp_principleId string
param functionsApp_principleId string
param location string
param user_id string

var userPermission = [
  user_id 
]

var appPermission = [
  webapp_principleId
  functionsApp_principleId
]

resource keyVault_resource 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: keyVault_name
  location: location
  properties:{
    accessPolicies:[[for (app, index) in appPermission: {
      objectId: app
      tenantId: tenant().tenantId
      permissions: {
        secrets: [ 'get', 'list' ]
      }
    }], [for (user, index) in userPermission: {
      objectId: user
      tenantId: tenant().tenantId
      permissions: {
        secrets: [ 'get', 'list', 'set' ]
      }
    }]]
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: tenant().tenantId
  }
}
```

But code above gives me next error:

> The enclosing array expected an item of type `AccessPolicyEntry`, but the provided item was of type `object[]`. bicep(BCP034)

According the documentation I've found it doesn't work like the code example. Is there a cast I need to do?

Comment: here you are passing an array of array, you need to merge the arrays together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of array to the `accessPolicies` property, you would need to concat both arrays:

```
param keyVault_name string
param webapp_principleId string
param functionsApp_principleId string
param location string
param user_id string

var userPermission = [
  user_id 
]

var appPermission = [
  webapp_principleId
  functionsApp_principleId
]

var userAccessPolicies = [for (user, index) in userPermission: {
  objectId: user
  tenantId: tenant().tenantId
  permissions: {
    secrets: [ 'get', 'list', 'set' ]
  }
}]

var appAccessPolicies = [for (app, index) in appPermission: {
  objectId: app
  tenantId: tenant().tenantId
  permissions: {
    secrets: [ 'get', 'list' ]
  }
}]

var accessPolicies = concat(userAccessPolicies, appAccessPolicies)
resource keyVault_resource 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: keyVault_name
  location: location
  properties:{
    accessPolicies:accessPolicies
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: tenant().tenantId
  }
}
```